# Trying to remap Win + [Shift] + Arrows using Autohotkey in Windows

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I am trying to write a script in Autohotkey to accomplish the following:

Win + Left, Win + Shift + Left = Home
Win + Right, Win + Shift + Right = End
etc.

It works with the simple version (Win + Arrow), but not when adding Shift to the combination. When pressing Shift together with Win and - let's say - left arrow, it moves the window to the other desktop (default windows 10 behaviour). Anyone can help with this? Here is my script:

```
#Left::
If GetKeyState("Shift","P")
  Send {Home}
else
  Send {Home}
Send {Home}
Return

#Right::
If GetKeyState("Shift","P")
  Send {End}
else
  Send {End}
Return

#Up::
If GetKeyState("Shift","P")
  Send {PgUp}
else
  Send {PgUp}
Return

#Down::
If GetKeyState("Shift","p")
  Send {PgDn}
else
  Send {PgDn}
Return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows 10 I've tried this and works.

```
#+Left::
Send {Home}
Return
```